# Http streaming with thin & eventmachine

Tags: ruby, streaming, eventmachine, thin

I'm playing with EM to achieve streaming and concurrency. I had a problem with streaming...
I run the following rack app https://gist.github.com/1394840 using

```
$ rackup -s thin -p 3000 async_app.ru
```

While testing with `$ ab -c 10 -n 20 http://localhost:3000/`, the app seemed accepting parellel requests. Great!

I expect it to achieve streaming meanwhile. When I test it in Firefox8, it works so well. And using `$ curl -i http://localhost:3000/`, the result is streamed just as expected too!

But later when tested in IE & Chrome, the streaming failed, that is, the three lines only showed up together 5 seconds after the request fired...

I doubted that if I miss something required by the browser? I noticed that there wasn't a `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` in the response headers, so does it matter? If so, is it Thin's problem? How can I implement streaming with thin, or in Chrome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently browsers won't start rendering a page until they get certain "amount" of response, as it pointed out [in this article](http://clientsize.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/chromefirefoxsafari-and-chunked-encoding/). So I've tried following:

```
  body.call ["Hey!\n".ljust(1024)]
```

I've tested it with Safari 6, Chrome 22 and Firefox 14 and they all start to work as expected when first message was no less than 1 Kb. Actually Safari started to print messages even if the first one was more than 512 bytes.