# Sinatra streaming in Chrome does not work

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, sinatra

I would like to streaming with sinatra 1.4.4. I used streaming example from sinatra documentation. When I tested it in Firefox 28.0 on Ubuntu 13.10 it works well. But the message showed up together after 1.5 seconds when I tested it in Chrome [Version 33.0.1750.152 Ubuntu 13.10 (256984)].

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/streaming' 

set server: :thin

get '/' do  
  stream do |out| 
    out << "It's gonna be legen -\n" 
    sleep 0.5 
    out << " (wait for it) \n" 
    sleep 1 
    out << "- dary!\n" 
  end 
end
```

I tried it with mongrel also, but I get the same result. I tried the answer from this question without success: [Http streaming with thin & eventmachine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275899/http-streaming-with-thin-eventmachine)

How do I need to modify my code or settings to work in Chrome? Is there any additional header information that chrome requires?